# iter function over table as input - does order matter and why?

Tags: kdb

I'm totally new to kdb+/q, and I found this problem below quite confusing to me. Just to simplify, we say we have this one line function `f` returns an one-row table with preset values, and I want to run this function over a combination of inputs x and y, like dates (list) and metas (table, with columns like orderid, px, size etc).

Now, I listed two ways to do so below. Since the function `f` doesn't really use any of the input, I would suppose the order of `x` and `y` doesn't matter since the difference is just which one is passed to `f` before another and only when two inputs passed would `f` starts to operate.

But why I got error in the second way, i.e. table follows the list?

Any idea and explanation is much appreciated.

```
f: {[x;y]
  ([] m: enlist `M; n: enlist `N)
  };

x: 1 2 3;
y: ([] a: 4 5 6; b: 7 8 9);

raze raze f ' [y] ' [x]; // this one works
raze raze f ' [x] ' [y]; // this one gives ERROR: length Explanation: Arguments do not conform
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is effectively equivalent to:

```
f:{y;1};
q)(f'[([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 3)])@/:1 2 3
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

(using extra brackets to make it clear the order of operation).
In this situation each one reduces to

```
q)f'[([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 3);1]
1 1 1
q)f'[([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 3);2]
1 1 1
q)f'[([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 3);3]
1 1 1
```

The "length" is ok here because the "y" values are atomic and kdb automatically expands those atomic values to match the length of the table. In order words, kdb treats these as:

```
q)f'[([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 3);1 1 1]
1 1 1
q)f'[([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 3);2 2 2]
1 1 1
q)f'[([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 3);3 3 3]
1 1 1
```

However, when you change the order it becomes:

```
(f'[1 2 3])@/:([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 3)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
f'[1 2 3;`a`b!1 4]
f'[1 2 3;`a`b!2 5]
f'[1 2 3;`a`b!3 3]
```

but now you do have a length problem because the dictionaries in the "y" variable are not atomic, they have length 2. Which doesn't match the length of the list (3).

Comment: Thank you very much. Crystal clear explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t say so but it looks like you are studying how to iterate a binary function `f` over list arguments, which has brought you to projecting `f'` onto `x`, which gives you a unary `f'[x]` that you then iterate over `y`. If that’s how we got here, what you want might be as simple as `x f'y`, which iterates `f` over corresponding items in `x` and `y`.

However, you mention *combinations* of inputs. If you want effectively a Cartesian product based on `f`, then combine the iterators [Each Right and Each Left](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right) to get `x f:/:\:y`.

That returns a matrix. You have razed your result. Depending on your argument types, you might be able to use [`cross`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cross/) to generate all the argument pair combinations, and [Apply](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/) Each `.'` to apply `f` to each pair:

```
f .' x cross y
```

Comment: Thanks! very informative answer :)